# Dynamic default from with Action Mailer Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Is it possible in Rails to set the default from in Action Mailer from an attribute in a Model, without having to set it every time in the actions?

I have a multi tenant app, with different tenants having different emails which has to be the default from in the mailer.

As per the Docs,

```
    default to:       -> { 'user@email.test' },
    from:     -> { method_that_retrieves_tenant_email }
```

should be possible, but when I try that, It throws the following error

```
    Failure/Error: from:     -> { method },
    ArgumentError:
    wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

I am using Rails 5.2.0 & ruby 2.3.1p112.

Additional Details:
This is what I have used

```
    class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base 
      default from: -> { tenant_email }
      .....

      private
      def tenant_email
        fetch_email
      end
```

Comment: Have you tried setting this from within the Mailer (rather than the model), but outside of the specific actions? You can set it from your app specific Mailers or from within the ApplicationMailer if they're all coming from the same email address.

Comment: Yeah. I have added in the ApplicationMailer. Please check the additional details section in the question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out that this works.

```
    class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

      after_action :set_default_from

    private

    def set_default_from
      mail.to = tenant_email
    end
```

Comment: This is old but I have to mention for everyone else looking for an answer that we used this method once and it's causing issues now. `mail` automatically renders the template and it messes up our condition where we can sometimes send a mail with API or SMTP. When it's API it won't send it but will still waste resources on rendering the template.